# Suggested edit: Should only tags removed be approved

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

While reviewing suggested edit, I frequently come across suggested edits that have only 1-2 tags removed nothing else is changed or touched. Suppose in an Android related post OP tagged `android-studio` though the question is not related to the IDE and someone just removed that tag. Should this be approved or rejected?

Comment: If the tag is irrelevant, then no. If it's relevant, depends on the post being edited. Is this the only edit? Are there any other important edits that should be done?

Comment: In some cases, people don't fix grammar and only add/remove tags. So, yes in some cases they ignore other edits.

Comment: and I find that some users, only add/remove tags to post frequently thats clearly just to increase their rep.

Comment: if there is only a tag edit while leaving other mistakes, either reject as too minor or edit.